# Cheap USB controlled DC voltage

Tags: voltage, usb, voltage-regulator, dac

Right now I'm using National Instruments DAQ boards, but I need to put together a few devices that require software control of a DC voltage in the 0-5v range. Update rate can be less than 1 Hz and 8 bits, and I don't need anything else on the NI DAQ, so paying a few hundred per channel isn't worthwhile.

I see a few cheap relay and variable resistor boards on Amazon, but surprisingly little for DC voltage output. What do people use for this?

Comment: You failed to mention what kind of load current do you need.

Comment: I have no preference.

Comment: What do you mean "no preference"? There is a big difference if you need 10A to your load, or just 1 mA or less.

Comment: Have you considered using a 8 bit latch and a R2R ladder?

Comment: By no preference I mean that I place no significance on output current and would like to consider all possible options.

Answer (score 2):

There are products of this kind, for example this [two-channel USB DAC](https://www.electronic-software-shop.com/lng/en/hardware/usb-dac-two-outputs-12-bit-4095-v.html),

[image]

It goes up to 4.095V, and has 50-Ohm impedance. But it is still ~$40 a piece.

Comment: What's [on topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is very clear. It's frustrating to see such high-rep users blatantly ignoring it.

Comment: Thanks, I had not seen that before. Is it possible to get this moved to a more appropriate place for instrumentation questions?

Comment: @pipe, I think the "on-topic" policy shouldn't be boldly applied across every question of this sort. This is an important question on USB controlled instrumentation. If someone knows a USB-controlled power supply, I would consider buying it myself. Unfortunately the stupid policy prohibits this kind of questions, I disagree with this policy and are not inclined to enforce it.